# Get position of image relative to parent, taking vertical-offset into consideration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two images next to each other in HTML. One image is taller than the other. Images have a `vertical-align: middle` CSS property. This causes the shorter image to be positioned lower, relative to the parent container, than the taller image.

I use the jQuery `.position()` method to get the images' position. The position.top for both images is the same, when clearly the shorter image is offset further towards the bottom because of the `vertical-align: middle` CSS property.

How can I get the image's actual position, taking into consideration the vertical difference caused by the `vertical-align: middle` CSS property?

UPDATE:

The problem happens because I do the following:

1. My HTML is output with the images having no src attributes. They do
   have a width and height, so the browser should not need to wait to
   load the actual image (later step) before calculating its position
2. I set the src attribute of each image
3. I check the position using jQuery. My guess is that the browser (FF
   9.0.1) waits to load the image before updating its position and making it available to JS

I will need to redesign my app so that this does not happen

Comment: Can you show the HTML, jQuery, and CSS?

Comment: My problem seems to be complicated by something not-so-straighforward. I just started setting up a simple demo of the behavior I am experiencing and in the simplest case the position of both images is being returned properly. Looking into this further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this.**

http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/X54gy/

```
small = parseInt($('img:eq(0)').css('height'));
big = parseInt($('img:eq(1)').css('height'));

difference = big - small;
top_distance = difference/2;

alert(top_distance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the height of the taller `div`, subtract from that the height of the `div` in question, and divide by 2. That will give you its offset from the parent `div`.

Answer (score 0):

[using jquery.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) would give you its actual position relative to the full body.
If you only want it relative to its parent, you could write a script as such;

```
function findPos(obj,till){
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

[(c) Peter-Paul Koch](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)